# Swift: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type Expected HTMLElement but found HTMLElement

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

I've searched the internet regarding this problem, but mine seems to be much special. I'm trying to parse a HTML document using queryselector as follow:

```
let doc = HTMLDocument(string: str)
      let elements = doc.querySelectorAll("script")
      elements.forEach { ddElement in
        if(ddElement.elementId == "js-competition"){
          scr = ddElement.textContent
```

and on elements.forEach line the program crashes with the following error:

*Precondition failed: NSArray element failed to match the Swift Array Element type Expected **HTMLElement** but found **HTMLElement***

[The error can be seen here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQxbI.png)

The fact that the expected type is the same with the found one, it's very weird. Everything was working fine, until I renamed the project and some updates for conversion to Swift 5 were triggered. The build is for iOS 15.2.

Did you face issues like this before? Because for me it looks like a xCode bug.

Thank you!

Comment: When you renamed the project did you also clean the build folder (and cleared the DerivedData folder)?

Comment: I've rolled back until that conversion, and seems to work fine now. Also, redone the renaming process and the problem and it didn't reappear. I didn't try what you mention, but i found out that what you suggested might solve that issue. I will keep that in mind for the next problems! Thank you for answering!

Comment: Ok, good that you manage to fix this. Please remove this question now since it has been resolved.